# In music how much Research and Theories are Independent from Trends and Traditions?

Tags: theory, musical-forms, musicology

What i belief that in music research and theories can't be certain unlike Mathematics, Science or somewhat Engineering discipline.

I think that first any composition with/without song came first intuitively and among them some make huge impact on certain audience and that impact needed to be recreate by other composer and they do studied those already ageless composition and that's how study of music began.

and as music is very vast and diverse there are lots of area has been emerged and that's how research of music has began.
so study of music is not different from study of Trends and Traditions and Research is also mostly in fashion why this pattern or style is trend and others not with/without some scientific approach.

so wanted to know is research and study in Music is different than studying Trends and Traditions? and how much certainty in this already done research in Music till now?

Comment: Theory describes - it doesn't dictate.

Comment: It was tough in the Winter of '77… having to change to playing long-sleeve punk with wooly jumpers, after a summer of carefree t-shirt & ripped jeans.

Comment: From Piston's Counterpoint introduction (page 11, Spanish edition) "But the fundamental deficiency of virtually all traditional methods is that they are not intended to communicate knowledge of the practice of composers, but they deploy a set of instructions to write music, even though, no one can know with certainty how the Music from here to only ten years will be written " Hope this illustrates something.

Comment: You could study "Trends and Traditions in Music" without having to do any reference to various theory schools, and vice versa.  I don't think your question reallly means much.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It's **to me** a valid question, as it address the ponderance of dogma in musical innovation. But as Tim said "Theory describes - it doesn't dictate".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a topic for discussion rather than a simple Q&A. It would be an excellent post for the chat room.

Comment: Yes `Theory Describes Don't Dictate` but how much theories are certain, on that someone could decide to stick and cover that for creation or not and its contradiction could make any negative impact or not that understanding is necessary so i did post this question here but yes its debatable thanks for your all concerns by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for sharing! I take the core of your question to be: How much does musicology—"music studies"—deal in measurable, quantifiable "certainties" that can be objectively observed and impassively analyzed... and how much does it deal in culturally-constructed abstracts and intangibles, subjective frameworks that we encounter subjectively?

First, I imagine there might be plenty of mathematicians and scientists who would take fright at describing their work as "certain" (at least, the good ones!).

Second, as you point out, "music studies" are very broad, and they encompass some disciplines within the hard sciences. The study of acoustics, or of the role of music in neuroscience or other medical concerns, can be subject to the scientific method. Even there, though, the scientist collides with cultural issues quickly: acoustics leads to psychoacoustics, which gets the objective researcher into the realm of subjective perception. Studies of the effect of music on the brain must contend with various musical traditions and experiences that affect people differently.

But yes, it's true that pretty much all the rest of musicology is some form of ethnography—a review of the practices of human cultures—and musicologists do themselves, their subjects, and their audience no favors when they forget it or pretend that it is not. Some disciplines, like so-called "ethnomusicology," wear this awareness on their sleeves, and conscientiously ground their musical observations within a wholistic survey of the surrounding culture—its histories, traditions, beliefs, resources, physical cultures, environmental impact, etc. But every really good music historian and theorist, even every performer—every musicologist worth their salt—bears in mind that the music they're talking about is a cultural artifact, the product of people, peoples, histories, economics, environments, beliefs, and ideologies.

Sometimes, if the scope of a discipline is narrow enough, the parameters are taken for granted. A Beethoven specialist can sit down to discuss a symphony without having to start with "Now, to really understand this we have to understand the impact Napoleon had on Europe, and to understand *that* we have to look at the Hundred Years' War..." And I can take a baroque orchestra gig and expect to be told exactly what pitch and temperament we'll be tuning to and which bow to bring, but take a modern symphony gig expecting these defaults to go without saying. But anyone who, even briefly and unconsciously, confuses these shorthand assumptions for universal truths—anyone who forgets, say, that "the dominant resolves to the tonic" holds true only for a certain scope of time and culture—runs all kinds of risks when they venture into the fringes of their defined scope. If I approach the music of Heinrich Biber without an awareness of his Bohemian boyhood I might miss some of his influences. If I play the music of Manuel Quiroga without understanding the mid-century surge of Galician nationalism, I miss the significance of his Galician *muñeira* as a political symbol.

All of which is to say: No, the study of music is not a "science." It is, perhaps, a "soft science," but it does very little to measure and explain the universe we live in, and much more to measure and explain the human beings living in it.

But—can it deal in "certainties"? Sure. As long as the certainties are observational and ethnographic. We can observe people making music; we can observe the notes they wrote. We can say, without hesitation, how Fux conceptualized counterpoint. We can point to a collection of dots on a page and call it a "C major chord," as long as we know we're talking about an idea that was constructed along with the dots themselves. We can be just as "certain" as any history or ethnography can be: we can simply observe and report what other humans do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer its quite elaborative over musicology. I do sometime feels that the one who study music too much unable to make or compose but the one who feels and connect with music better can surely make or compose remarkable and impactful music. and the one who can follow trends and market can sell music better without even creating good composition so do had questions in mind about theories certainties. and you did explain pretty good that things in music that are observable ethnographic are certainly adaptable among all ,thanks.